# How to override include_once pointed file using add_filter?

Tags: filters, hooks

I want to customize a plugin which uses a file called html-vendor-order-page.php to define the style of contents:

```
include_once( apply_filters( 'wcpv_vendor_order_page_template', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/views/html-vendor-order-page.php' ) );
```

I want to create my own html-vendor-order-page.php by modifying this file and force the plugin to use this file instead by using add_filter.

I was thinking to filter `__FILE__` which is a defined constant to point to my file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just filter `__FILE__`. Or any arbitrary function or variable. You can only filter values that are passed to `apply_filters()`. In this case the `wcpv_vendor_order_page_template` filterable value is:

```
dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/views/html-vendor-order-page.php'
```

In other words, it's a path to a PHP file. If you want to change the PHP file that's loaded, you can filter `wcpv_vendor_order_page_template` to pass the path to a file in your theme.

So if you create a version of this file in `wp-content/{yourtheme}/wcpv//views/html-vendor-order-page.php`, you can make the plugin load that version like this:

```
add_filter(
    'wcpv_vendor_order_page_template',
    function( $path ) {
        return get_theme_file_path( 'wcpv//views/html-vendor-order-page.php' );
    }
);
```